# Select a AuthenticationScheme without using Authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

Authentication = Who is calling?
Authorization  = Are they allowed to do it?

I have several calls to `AddJwtBearer` in my code.  It creates a couple different JWT scenarios that I support.

I also have set `options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "MyAuthenticationScheme"`.

When a call comes in to a controller's method that does NOT have a `[Authorize]` tag on it, then it will set the `User.Identity` object to the data in the JWT that was setup in the call to `AddJwtBearer` for `"MyAuthenticationScheme"`.

However, if that JWT was not there, the call goes through and the `User.Identity` object just has empty values in it.  That is great for what I want.

I am hoping that there is a way to add an attribute to my method in my controller that lets me switch the AuthenticationScheme WITHOUT having to use `[Authorize]`.

My reasoning is that I am just trying to setup the "Who is calling" (Authentication).  For now, I have another system that takes care of the "What can you do" (Authorization).

**On a per controller method basis, is there a way to switch AuthenticationSchemes without having to use the `[Authorize]` attribute?**

Something like `[Authentication (Scheme = "MyOtherAuthenticationScheme")]`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add the `AllowAnonymous` along with your `Authorize` attribute.

```
 [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]
 [AllowAnonymous]
```

Answer (score 0):

To explicitly authenticate using particular scheme you can use `HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync("SchemeName")` (extension method). This is of course not a per-controller approach, but you can probably insert this into some interception mechanizm, like MVC filter or a custom authentication middleware extension (e.g. via `IAuthenticationRequestHandler`)